# Missing variable value in CURL call from playbook

Tags: bash, curl, ansible

I have an ansible that reads in data from a file and then call a bash script that needs the data from the file. Bash file has a CURL call making using of the data pass to the script from the playbook.
With the error. I am seeing it looks like the variable is not getting passed properly to the CURL call

File:

```
com.boomi.container.id=aa186a63-f285-45e6-9a1e-afda36c7f59f
com.boomi.container.account=12HJB
```

Playbook

```
- hosts: localhost 
  vars:
     contents: "{{ lookup('file', 'container.id') }}"
  tasks:
     - debug: msg="the value of container.id is {{ contents }}"
     - set_fact:
          atomID: >-
            {{
              lookup('file', 'container.id')
                | regex_search('com\.boomi\.container\.id=(.*)', '\1')
                | first
            }}
     - debug: msg="the value of container.id is {{atomID}}"     
     - command:  "sh eko.sh {{atomID}}"
       register: command_result
     - debug:
        var: command_result.stdout_lines
```

Bash Script

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
# set -x

user=user@xyz.com
passsword=2yu3990!£

curl -u "$user:$password" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" -s \
    https://api.boomi.com/api/rest/v1/FQ67wer/SharedServerInformation/${atomID} \
    | python -m json.tool
```

Task Execution Result

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "command_result.stdout_lines": [
        "{",
        "    \"@type\": \"Error\",",
        "    \"message\": \"ID of object to get must not be blank or null\"",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your above example. But the one really preventing you to get the expected result is that you are using an undefined variable in your final script. And I suspect this is because you mixed-up ansible variables and bash environment vars.

Your bash script is trying to use directly `$atomID` (that you can secure as `${atomID}`) which is not set anywhere in your script or containing shell environment. You are passing the value to your script as the first positional parameter in your command so it will be retrieved as `$1`. If you don't assign at some point `atomID=$1`, your script cannot guess that on its own.

Moreover, you are making very complicated operations to get your container id. `container.id` is a properties file (i.e. an ini file without sections) and ansible has an [`ini` lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ini_lookup.html) to retrieve such values out of the box.

To test my example playbook, I modified your script so it can get the value from the passed parameter. I also `chmod u+x` the file so I can run in directly from command/shell:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Assign a value to bash variable atomID from positional parameter 1
# Set to "undefined" if there is no parameter
atomID=${1:-undefined}

# Simple test: print out the atomID - Replace with your actual code
echo atomID is ${atomID}
```

The playbook:

```yaml
- name: Run a script with parameter from ini file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    atomID: "{{ lookup('ini', 'com.boomi.container.id type=properties file=container.id') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show parsed atomID if `-v` is passed to playbook command
      debug:
        var: atomID
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Run our script with the given parameter
      command: eko.sh {{ atomID }}
      register: run_script

    - name: Show script result
      debug:
        var: run_script.stdout
```

And the result:

```
# use -v if you want to see the first debug value
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [Run a script with parameter from ini file] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show parsed atomID] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Run our script with the given parameter] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Show script result] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "run_script.stdout": "atomID is aa186a63-f285-45e6-9a1e-afda36c7f59f"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Perfect Solution and also helped to make the code more readable with ini look up. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for letting me know on the tick mark
Very minor change I made is `command: eko.sh {{ atomID }}` as `"sh command: eko.sh {{ atomID }}"`

Comment: I precised in my answer that I `chmod u+x` the script file so it can be executed directly. Moreover, using `sh` to launch a script that starts with a `bash` shebang is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Ah Sorry. Agree with you on the chmod.